# How can I make cowsay say something every time I close the terminal?

Tags: bash, scripts

I want cowsay to print something like "have a nice day" when I close the terminal. I know I have to have some kind of script, but I'm not even sure how to write a script or how to use it once it's written. Any advice?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could try adding the line:

```
trap 'cowsay "Have a nice day!"; sleep 1' EXIT
```

to your `.bashrc` file.